# What happen if i connect the capacitors with few LED Strip in parallel?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, capacitance, led-strip, supercapacitor

I want to make my LED Strips which connected in parallel to dim out slowly. Therefore, i thought of using few capacitors (in parallel) to make this possible.
if i"m using 12V batery as power supply and few LED strips with different length, my qustion is: 
1) if i using the capasitors in the circut, will the voltage drop on the through the every LED Strips be the same??? 
2) is the discharged time for capacitors would be the same as if i use one LED strip?

Comment: the LED strips would be practically off at ~10V, so you would waste a lot of energy..

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Will the voltage drop [through] every LED Strips be the same???

Yes, because they're in parallel. Which means that if the LED strips are different lengths, *the voltage drop through each LED won't be the same.*

> 2) Is the discharge time for capacitors [the same] as if I use one LED strip?

No, the current through the capacitor will be higher so it will discharge faster. You could use a higher-value capacitor to compensate for this.

Comment: Not sure if the last paragraph makes sense.  I consider question 2 as multiple LED strips **discharging** capacitors.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat A higher-value capacitor will take longer to discharge.

Comment: Yes, makes sense now.